# Jquery returning same index for last row and second last row of html table

Tags: jquery, html, css-tables

i have an html table, as follows

```
  <div class="filesList">
                        <table id="tblFiles">
                            <tr style=" ">
                                <td class="td1"> File Name1 </td>
                                <td class="td2"></td>
                                <td class="td3" > - </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style=" ">
                                <td class="td1"> File Name2 </td>
                                <td class="td2"></td>
                                <td class="td3" > - </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style=" ">
                                <td class="td1"> File Name3 </td>
                                <td class="td2"></td>
                                <td class="td3"  > - </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Now, i am using this code to get index of row clicked. i.e. user click in 3rd column of a row and i get the index of the clicked row.

```
$('#tblFiles').on('click', "td:nth-child(3)", function (e) {
    var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').index();  
    alert('Row#: ' + row + ', Column#: ' + col);
 });
```

problem i am having is, it return same row index of last and second last row.
i.e. it return 2 for 2nd and 3rd row.

i have also tried following ways to get row index, but same problem

```
 row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());

 row = parseInt($(this).parent().index()) ;
```

kindly help.
imran

Comment: I have just tested this and it is working as intended with JQuery 1.9.1. http://jsfiddle.net/hx42rtch/

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```html
    <html>    
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
    <table id="tblFiles" cellpadding="5" border="2">
    <tr style=" ">
                                    <td class="td1"> File Name1 </td>
                                    <td class="td2"></td>
                                    <td class="td3" > - </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style=" ">
                                    <td class="td1"> File Name2 </td>
                                    <td class="td2"></td>
                                    <td class="td3" > - </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style=" ">
                                    <td class="td1"> File Name3 </td>
                                    <td class="td2"></td>
                                    <td class="td3"  > - </td>
                                </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
    
    $('#tblFiles').on('click', "td", function (e) { 
        var row = parseInt($(this).parent().index())+1;
        var column = parseInt($(this).index())+1;  
        alert('Row#: ' + row + ', Column#: ' + column );
     });
    
    </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```